# Problema com autoplay de vídeos no Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou tendo problemas para inserir um vídeo com autoplay em uma página de um site, quando esta página é aberta no Chrome, o vídeo fica parado até que se clique no botão "play".

Li em diversos "posts" que se trata de um "bug" e a sugestão é inserir o atributo "muted" na tag vídeo, porém o vídeo fica mudo e preciso que além do vídeo começar a rodar automaticamente que este também possua som.

Tentei habilitar o som via jQuery, porém não obtive sucesso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Mas o que vc quer? Que ele já comece rodando e com som?

Comment: "É sabido deste bug", qual bug? Qual é o resultado esperado e qual o desejado?

Comment: Com uma rápida pesquisa dá para descobrir que [não é um bug](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/09/unified-autoplay.html) e sim uma medida da Google para melhorar a experiência do usuário. Ou você ativa o `autoplay` no mudo ou vai ter que pesquisar mais a fundo para entender como a Google julga quais vídeos podem e quais não podem tocar automaticamente com som.

Comment: Sim gostaria que iniciasse rodando e com som. Li vários posts que tratam como bug e sinalizaram que o Google pretende corrigir.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("video").prop('muted', bool)` para ativar ou desativar o som e `$("video").prop('muted')` para verificar se o mesmo está mudo.

**Exemplo**

```js
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$("#mute-video").click(function() {
  if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
    $("video").prop('muted', false);
  } else {
    $("video").prop('muted', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mute-video">Mudo</button>
<video src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/servingsites-videos/firstbaptistchurchofnorfolk/sample-welcome-video-2.mp4" controls width="240"></video>
```